# How to set KVM Kernel boot "only once"?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am trying using automation install via KVM. The step is :

1. Load Kernel and initrd from disk
2. It will install customized Linux to HDD, and automatically reboot
3. Boot from HDD

So I use this command to install my customized linux :

```
virt-install --name Kernel_Test --ram 16384 --vcpus=8 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel6 --vnc --hvm --disk path=/kvm_images//Kernel_Test.qcow2,device=disk,format=qcow2,size=50,bus=sata --boot hd,kernel=/tmp/my_vmlinuz,initrd=/tmp/my_image,kernel_args="append stage2=initrd:" --network bridge=bridge1,model=virtio --network bridge=bridge1,model=virtio --network bridge=bridge0,model=virtio
```

However, it will get stuck in a loop, as follows:

1. Boot from kernel/initrd -> installation completed
2. Restart
3. Boot from kernel/initrd -> installation completed
4. Restart
5. (loop)

I have tried to use the following command to strip kernel related configuration, without success:

```
virsh dumpxml <VMNAME> >> vmname.xml
(do something to change vmname.xml, strip kernel/initrd boot part)
virsh define vmname.xml
```

It will still keep looping, and when I `dumpxml` again, it still holds kernel/initrd boot configuration.

Because I need to automatic installation, how can I let KVM only boot once from destinated kernel/initrd? I have set boot sequence `--boot hd,` in front of `kernel= ...`, but it just skips it and keesp booting from local kernel/initrd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a direct kernel boot is present, it will always be used, and the regular boot order will be ignored.

The *best* way to handle this is to not use direct kernel boot for installing the system, but rather pass a `--location` where the Linux distribution you are installing lives (which can be on a local disk or a remote web server, FTP or NFS server). This also allows you to inject a local kickstart or preseed file for a completely automated installation. For example:

```
--boot hd --location http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64 --initrd-inject=my_vm.ks --extra-args="ks=file:/my_vm.ks"
```

If you can't do that for some reason, then pass `--noreboot` and hack the XML after virt-install exits. You will have to restart the VM manually. Remember that virt-install can exit *before* the installation completes, so simply restarting the VM won't work reliably and could interrupt an installation in progress.

Comment: Thanks!  --noreboot seems exactly what I need. I can keep probing VM status and when it shut off, I can `virsh dumpxml` `virsh define` to change configuration then `virsh start`.

Comment: @Rayer That will work. But I still strongly recommend you use `--location` instead, if you are installing one of its supported distributions (RHEL/CentOS, Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, SuSE, and a couple of more obscure ones listed in the man page). But if you insist on going that route, I have [a few bash functions](https://gist.github.com/error10/90ba6944284d2980a41a) that might help you out.